# Import differing text files and build a database

Tags: python, database, text

I have text files that contain tables that I have extracted from pdfs.
Some text files contain 1 table and some contain 2 or more. They are all in CSV format.

I want to import them into python, save them as a dataframe and build a database. Each textfile is for a different company (fake data).

My End goal is something that looks like this:

| Company | Executive | Year | Cash Salary and Fees | Cash STI/Bonus | Non-monetary Benefits | Superannuation | Annual and Long Service Leave | Deferred STI | LTI Awards | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | John Doe | 2023 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| AA | John Doe | 2022 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| AA | Greg Doe | 2023 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| AA | Greg Doe | 2022 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| BB | Steve Doe | 2023 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| BB | Steve Doe | 2022 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| BB | Alice Doe | 2023 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |
| BB | Alice Doe | 2022 | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX | XXXX |

A problem that I will run into is that the headings for the tables are not always the same. So when building the database if the headings are the same I am obviously happy to merge the data. Otherwise I am happy to create a new column ( I dont want to lose data)

Another thing is you can see below sometimes the text file has the table name and sometimes it doesnt, so importing this into python I have to handle this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

2 examples of my text files are below

**File1:**

```
Table 1:
Executive Name, Year, Fees/Salary, Cash Bonus, Non-monetary Benefit, Superannuation, Cash settled share based payments, Equity settled share-based payments, Total, Percentage of remuneration related to performance, Cash Bonus as a percentage of maximum achievable
Timothy Burnett, 2023, 110481, -, -, 11601, -, -, 122082, -, -
Greg Fletcher, 2023, 72118, -, -, 7573, -, -, 79691, -, -
Nick Yates, 2023, 72118, -, -, 7573, -, -, 79691, -, -
Mark Benson, 2023, 548239, 353243, 14427, 27132, -, 107601, 1050642, 43.9%, 82.0%
Brett Gregory, 2023, 184384, 67242, -, 13256, 48516, -, 313398, 36.9%, 82.0%
Rudy Sheriff, 2023, 289245, 80000, 3303, 16862, -, -, 389410, 20.5%, 98.0%

Table 2:
Executive Name, Year, Fees/Salary, Cash Bonus, Non-monetary Benefit, Superannuation, Cash settled share based payments, Equity settled share-based payments, Total, Percentage of remuneration related to performance, Cash Bonus as a percentage of maximum achievable
Timothy Burnett, 2022, 104545, -, -, 10455, -, -, 115000, -, -
Greg Fletcher, 2022, 68182, -, -, 6818, -, -, 75000, -, -
Nick Yates, 2022, 68182, -, -, 6818, -, -, 75000, -, -
Mark Benson, 2022, 516813, 280404, 13185, 23568, -, 111300, 945270, 41.4%, 86.0%
Rudy Sheriff, 2022, 326637, 97141, 6192, 23568, -, 34932, 488470, 27.0%, 90.0%
```

**File2**

```
Name,Year,Salary and Fees,Cash Bonus,Non-monetary Benefits,Long Service Leave,Superannuation,Options,Total,Performance Related
I M Williams (Chair),2023,110406,-,-,-,11490,-,121896,NA
I M Williams (Chair),2022,70471,-,-,-,7079,-,77550,NA
R L Green,2023,85317,-,-,-,8881,-,94198,NA
R L Green,2022,63278,-,-,-,6331,-,69609,NA
M R Stubbs,2023,85317,-,-,-,8881,-,94198,NA
M R Stubbs,2022,52853,-,-,-,5285,-,58138,NA
S P Cantwell,2023,87799,-,-,-,6865,-,94664,NA
S P Cantwell,2022,34912,-,-,-,3491,-,38403,NA
A R Kelly (resigned 5 November 2021),2023,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,NA
A R Kelly (resigned 5 November 2021),2022,22305,-,-,-,2233,-,24538,NA
R A Anderson (resigned 31 August 2021),2023,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,NA
R A Anderson (resigned 31 August 2021),2022,14224,-,-,-,1427,-,15651,NA
Sub-Total,2023,368839,-,-,-,36117,-,404956,NA
Sub-Total,2022,258043,-,-,-,25846,-,283889,NA
```

Comment: hi there! 1. are you wanting to use r or python? 2. is `-` NA or 0?

Comment: also *"They are all in CSV format"* hmmm you say that, but the fact that you then go on to say *"the text file has the table name and sometimes it doesnt"* tells me that they aren't. Comma Separated Value files are rectangular, they don't have a random title at the start

Comment: also 3. is it right to assume that there will always be the same columns within one file, and 4. would we ever have data for the same person and the same year in different files (e.g. Timothy Burnett's 2022 Options data in File2 or another file

Comment: @ KJ I don’t think you paid attention to my question I am working with many text files all of different types. It is not simple. Please read the question